# How to specify properties to ignore in valueMap with Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

My customer vertex has 4 properties. If I need a map representation of those properties I can get them by executing

```
g.V('customerId').valueMap('firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName', 'age')
```

But, if I need all properties excluding `age` in my map, is there a way to specify just the list of ignored properties? Something like

```
g.V('customerId').valueMap(not('age'))
```

I want to avoid specifying all the required properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer Kfir provided is good. Another way is a bit more direct in my mind because you don't have the expense of first creating a `Map`, deconstructing it to filter, and then putting it back together:

```
gremlin> g.V().map(properties().hasKey(without('age')).group().by(key()).by(value()))
==>[name:marko]
==>[name:vadas]
==>[name:lop,lang:java]
==>[name:josh]
==>[name:ripple,lang:java]
==>[name:peter]
```

This approach just explodes vertices to properties, filters the key you don't want and then constructs a `Map` from that.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for the your suggestion. I like it for being more optimal, except that most of the time you would also need the vertex ID, which can be retrieved with valueMap(true), but not with properties AFAIK.

Comment: true and good point. though I think that in a case where i needed the id, i would probably stick to this approach and just union in the ID, so as to avoid the destruct/construct of the `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in step for it.

You can achieve this goal by unfolding each map, filter the unwanted properties (keys), and regroup it again:

```
g.V().valueMap().local(unfold()
    .where(select(keys).is(without(["age","prop1","prop2"])))
    .group().by(select(keys)).by(select(values)))
```

Comment: Thanks mate! This is such a help! Can you recommend a good tutorial or material to study and understand how traversal/gremlin data structures work?

Comment: Besides the TinkerPop documentation of all steps, you have Kelvin Lawrence book which is very comprehensive: http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html